# Nodemailer. Verify if two emails are sending correctly

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Good morning and thank you in advance.
I put you in situation... I'm designing my first "professional" website and it have a form with personal data and the user have to attach confidential private document. When sending it, the app generates a PDF that is sent to the user to serve as proof of having made the request correctly and sends to my client that PDF and the documents attach in the form. You can not give the situation that you send an email but not the second, so, Would there be any way to verify that both emails will be sent correctly and that only in that situation will the be sent?

I'm using `node.js` on the server side and `nodemailer` to send the data.

Thanks

PD: Excuse my level of English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Systems can fail due to any reasons, we must have backup plans, it depends on your use case how you handle the backup plans.

One approach to your problem statement can be you can have some key in Redis (or any cache database) to check if both emails are sent, if not you can retry sending the pending email.

Comment: I understand the logic, thank you very much. I will try to do something similar with my knowledge